# Rest assured - Create Json file with expected return from an API called internally in test

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest-assured

I'm using rest assured to develop test integrations, inside these there are calls to other microservices.
There are test scenarios where I really wouldn't want to call these microservices and for those cases I would like to simulate the return in a file with the expected json.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think wiremock is the thing you're looking for. https://wiremock.org/

Comment: As Lucas mentioned, you need some sort of mocking framework to return predifined response in this case. Wiremock or Mockito are both fine for this case.